# Limiting Environment.yml Dependencies by Operating System

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, yaml, conda

I have an `environment.yml` and I have two dependencies that are only windows.  Is there a tag I can add to not install this package in the environment.yml?

I've tried adding the `[win]` tag after the dependency in the environment.yml and that causes the installation to fail.

```
name: awesome_dev_env
channels:
- anaconda
- conda-forge
- dhirschfeld
- defaults
- fastai
- pytorch
dependencies:
- beautifulsoup4
- requests
- requests-kerberos==0.11.0
- requests-toolbelt
- requests_ntlm
- requests-oauthlib
- requests-negotiate-sspi  [win]
- winkerberos  [win]
```

The result of this environment should be a Python environment with a bunch of request libraries.  Instead I get an error stating that [win] tag is invalid.  Is there a way to restrict the libraries by OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, **there is no way to do this from within a YAML**.  There is [an open issue to add such a feature](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8089), but unfortunately no one from the community has volunteered to add it.